# Coloring entries in an Matrix/2D-numpy array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, colors

I'm learning python3 and I'd like to print a matrix/2d-array which is color-coded (CLI). So let's say I'd like to assign each of these integers a certain background color, creating a mosaic-style look.

I've figured out how to fill a matrix of a given size with random integers, but I can't wrap my head around on how to continue from here on to achieve background coloring for each individual entry in the matrix, depending on its value. This is how far I've come:

```py
from random import randint
import numpy as np

def generate():
    n = 10
    m = 0
    map = np.random.randint(4 + 1, size=(n, n))
    print(map)

    for element in np.nditer(map):
        # iterating over each column is probably not the way to go...


generate()
```

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of iterating through every column of the matrix and check by several if conditions whether the entry is 0,1,2,3 or 4 and, based on the condition, append that value with a certain background color to a new matrix, but I assume there is a far more elegant way to do this...

Comment: You could plot a heatmap of the array

Comment: Don't use `nditer`.  It doesn't make iteration through an array any easier or faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will `print` a colored output on console...

```
>>> map = np.random.randint(4 + 1, size=(10, 10))
>>> def get_color_coded_str(i):
...    return "\033[3{}m{}\033[0m".format(i+1, i)
... 
>>> map_modified = np.vectorize(get_color_coded_str)(map)
>>> print("\n".join([" ".join(["{}"]*10)]*10).format(*[x for y in map_modified.tolist() for x in y]))
>>>
```

[image]

To add background color use following `fn`

```
>>> def get_color_coded_str(i):
...    return "\033[4{}m{}\033[0m".format(i+1, i)
```

[image]

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np

def get_color_coded_str(i):
    return "\033[3{}m{}\033[0m".format(i+1, i)

def get_color_coded_background(i):
    return "\033[4{}m {} \033[0m".format(i+1, i)

def print_a_ndarray(map, row_sep=" "):
    n, m = map.shape
    fmt_str = "\n".join([row_sep.join(["{}"]*m)]*n)
    print(fmt_str.format(*map.ravel()))

n = 10
m = 20
map = np.random.randint(4 + 1, size=(n, m))
map_modified = np.vectorize(get_color_coded_str)(map)
print_a_ndarray(map_modified)
back_map_modified = np.vectorize(get_color_coded_background)(map)
print("-------------------------------------------------------")
print_a_ndarray(back_map_modified, row_sep="")
```

PS: print function modified as suggested by @hpaulj

Comment: Your `print` function might be clearer if split into two lines.  One to define the format string: `fmt = "\n".join([row_sep.join(["{}"]*m)]*n)`, and one to apply it to the array input: `print(fmt.format(*map.ravel()))`.

Comment: Oh that is great! I didn't realize this can be done without iterating through the entire thing.! EDIT: nervermind, I overlooked the for-loops. STILL: it's way more efficient than I would have done it. So Thanks Alot!

Comment: @MaxPower8993 eventhough the print uses looping, the mat creation of stored bg values is actually vectorized

Comment: @vmandke Thank you for sharing this valid solution. I just want to add that for some Windows users, colors may not end up showing. [The answer by Glenn Slayden (the highest voted one as of this writing)](https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling/) is what I followed (as a Windows 10 user), to get it to work.

Comment: @MoAboulmagd thanks!!! This is very interesting, I haven't really ever worked on windows, so just assumed that Python would be handling the lower abstractions, and throw appropriate errors...